# ¿Cómo mostrar mensaje al dar click sobre un JMenu?

Tags: java, java-swing

En la siguiente línea agrego el `Listener`:

```
jMenuAbout.addActionListener(new AtbashUIController());
```

El siguiente es el método ActionPerformed:

```
 @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Mi mensaje");
    }
```

Pero cuándo le doy `click` al `JMenu` no pasa nada, tampoco genera errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería añadir un [MenuListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MenuListener.html) al `JMenu` que sería lo más adecuado.

```
JMenu jMenuAbout = new JMenu("Archivo");
jMenuAbout.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
 @Override
 public void menuSelected(MenuEvent me) {
    System.out.println("SE SELECCIONO EL MENÚ");
 }

 @Override
 public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent me) {
   System.out.println("NO SELECCIONO EL MENÚ");
 }

 @Override
 public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent me) {}
});
```